# Can a US government agency create a private company outside of Congress or rulemaking?

Tags: congress, government

Can a US government agency such DoD create a private company by simple mandate, without either going through formal rulemaking or without an act of Congress? Specifically, to create a single company that would then receive sole-source contract from that agency. The company would ***not*** be a US government-owned company (Federal government corporation), but entirely private.

I understand Congress can create private companies through the passage of laws. That's not the case in this scenario. Instead, the scenario is that a lower-level department within the government agency would hold a brief "Industry Day" event and then simply issue a public declaration that the private organization would be formed and automatically granted a sole-source contract.

Comment: If the agency is creating the company, but does not own it, who owns it? Probably someone at the agency could ask those owners to form a company, but I'm not sure why the agency would be able to just create a company on their behalf when you or I couldn't.

Comment: This is the problem. In the scenario above, which represents a real-world occurrence, the resulting company is a non-profit operated by friends of the government employee who mandated its formation. I don't want to get too deep into the corruption angle, though, and want to limit this question (at least) as to whether the government can even create a company outside of rulemaking or actual passage of a law.

Comment: Was the creation of the organization really *mandated*?  What's more common is that the government announces that they want to award a contract to get something done, and if no company or organization currently exists that could do it, perhaps *encourages* the private sector to form one - even if that organization would have the government as its only client.  The "declaration" in your example could instead simply be an *announcement* that some individuals have agreed to *voluntarily* create an appropriate organization.

Comment: No, DoD published a formal RFI to gather information on forming the company, then held a public Industry Day to meet with people in order to do just that. The announcement specifically said the DoD will "Establish the [organization] inclusive of a Board of Directors." During the event itself, the government then left the room and told them to "self-organize," but without the DoD's RFI and public announcements, none of it would have occurred. And there were dozens of existing companies that could provide the service sought by the DoD.

Comment: So, technically, some people, chosen without any kind of bidding process, formed a company, at the direction of and with the help of a government agency, which then gave that company what might be special treatment. And the question is, is that process as a whole allowed?

Comment: I want to be accurate. The government saw a problem with its supply chain. DoD decided it would try to fix this problem without any Federal spending. So it organized to create a private company to do it, on behalf of the government. It mandated the creation of that company, and then gave the company a sole-source contract to oversee this program. But the government did not create this company through any formal rulemaking process nor via passage of a law. The question is whether this is some other way the FedGov can create companies, making this legal. (Ignore the cronyism for now.)